# Drupal multi-site and one theme: how to know which multi-site user is on?

Tags: drupal, themes, drupal-7, drupal-themes

I have drupal multisite installed and atm I have two sites. Both sites uses same theme, but there are few tiny differences between looks of the site (like logo and div/bar is different color). Or well I would that they would have those differences. Now the question is how can I know on theme template that which site is showing up? Is there some paremeter or variable somewhere? Basically so that I could do is simple php if clause (if its this site, show this div and its the other site dnot show it)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my project I had the similar problem. What I did was that in template.php I created the following function:

```
function mytheme_firstdomain() {
  global $base_url;
  if(strpos($base_url,"http://firstsubdomain.mydomain") !== false) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

And then I could call this in the page.tpl.php code. Like

```
<?php if(mytheme_firstdomain()) { ?>
   <div>Only for first domain</div>
<?php } else { ?>
   <div>Only for the second domain</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Otherwise you could look into Block Classes module. That could also help.

Comment: Hmm, that seem some how dirty way to do it. Surely there's a proper way of doing this?

Comment: Yes. It is kind of dirty. But I didn't find any drupal variable to look into.